# Opening SWT Image in im4java

Tags: java, image, swt, im4java

I have a SWT application where the user can drag and drop images onto a canvas.
After dropping I keep track of the image in an SWT.graphics.Image Instance.

Now I want to edit the image using im4java and display the Image on the canvas object.
But I am stuck at getting the Image into the IMOperation Object.

```
Image i = this.image; //image is stored in here
ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
//how can i edit the image data using the op object?
```

Is it possible to edit the Image object this way?

Edit: I am trying to be more specific here:
I know how to load an image into the Operation using:

```
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage("myimage.jpg");
```

But in my case I do not want to load the image via filename but I want to use the Image instance instead.

```
op.setImageData(i.getImageData()) //does sth like this exist?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. You can:

1. Use `BufferedImage`s and show them in an embedded AWT control.
2. Use `BufferedImage`s and [convert them to/from SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498467/conversion-from-bufferedimage-to-swt-image). This is slow (in my experience) and may not work for all images.
3. Use [`ImageLoader`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/ImageLoader.html) to work with [input/output streams](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html#piping).

Comment: Thanks. I am now using ImageLoader to save a temporary image which I use as input image for the image operation.